# Get the new value from a combobox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

This is an odd issue that I can't seem to find an answer for I have a Combo Box with data from a dataset.  I want to get the value from the dataset when the user selects a new value so I can update the database with the new value, but the problem is I get the value of what was already there instead of the new value

For example if the emp's status is currently "Part Time" and I change it to "Full Time" the value returned below from cbEmpStatus (the combobox) is "Part Time"

```
Private Sub cbEmpStatus_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbEmpStatus.Leave
    Dim dbConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim updateQry As String = "Update tbl_Employee Set Status='" & cbEmpStatus.Text & "'"

    MsgBox(updateQry)

End Sub
```

I don't want to use SelectedValueChanged or SelectedINdex Changed because the Combobox updates based on the employee selected and I don't want it to fire off the update process everytime I select a different employee from the datagrid

Comment: could you store it as a public variable and then compare to see if it has changed, or are you looking for a handler that runs when the user leaves the control?

Comment: I'm looking for something that will update the database anytime the dropdown is changed, but I don't want to execute the updateqry every time I select a different employee who has a different status

Comment: so couldn't you just use SelectedValueChanged or SelectedINdex and check if the employee has a "different status" before you update the database?

Comment: But then I would still have to do a call to the database to check the old value.  It would defeat the purpose

Comment: could you load all the user status in a public data table, then check through that with a loop, if that results in a difference then do an update